# Phonegap page not scaling correctly on Android 2.2

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, mobile-website, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm using Phonegap to load an HTML/Jquery driven website.
It runs fine on 3.0, but when I run on a 2.2 simulator a few problems happen:

Screen resolution is much too zoomed in
Loss of real-estate (the sides of the screens are black)
Can't scroll to see entire page

It's just a new project -> add Phonegap library -> add my www folder.

Anyone know why this happens? Is there something I need to set in my HTML, or my Android XML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set the following values in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```